# How to show all share options in android?

Tags: android, share

I am developing an Android app and want to share some text by opening all the
share options available in device. But currently the list is showing Email, bluetooth, Gmail and  messaging.

Other apps like BBC news are showing more options in the same device like Bump, Picasa,  and others. How to show all available options and handle them?

I am using this:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/vcard");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,mailBody);            
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));
```

and in manifest

```
 <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
  </intent-filter>
```

Comment: if not get solved then use `<data android:mimeType="image/*">` instead of  `<data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>` this will show you all options including Bump, Picasa

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because you're only showing intents registered to handle `text/vcard` Instead use

```
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
```

Comment: after sharing by bluttoth or by sms or anything it give me black     screen how to overcome this so that it take me to my previous screen

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent i=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Subject test");
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "extra text that you want to put");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Share via"));
```

Comment: @AndDev21 Happy to help,If this answer helped you,then please mark it as accepted,so it may help others also.Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 0):

for sharing text only use
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
 And for sgaring image Use
sharingIntent.setType("image/*");