# How to get all share apps (installed on the device) in a list?

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, share

i want to get share list and to to be able to share text, i used this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329851/how-to-show-all-share-option-in-android) but there were weaknesses such as the Gmail with empty subject filed and the facebook was shown in list but doesn't work with the share.

i searched for long time but didn't find the complete answer.

please help.

NOTE: i just want to share text with links nothing more.

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally handled by using `intent.setData(uri)` with a URI that has the schema set to a relevant value. For instance if you wanted to share via email apps you might use the scheme 'mailto'

Edit:
Facebook specific example - The following will work to share with facebook - the bit to note for facebook is it seems like your EXTRA_TEXT needs to be JUST a link or CONTAIN at least one link otherwise Facebook doesn't like it...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is text from http://www.myapp.com");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```

Comment: Would you please complete your answer? I used this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/02/share-with-intents.html), but the facebook doesn't share my text and link?

Comment: I've added an example For facebook, its backwards compatible with their older versions if you supply ONLY a link (no other text), they are focused on doing sharing via the SDK now